# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when surfing to an app hosted by Docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I developed a Node.js app. I could run it using `node bin/www` and then I could reach it on the browser at http://localhost:3000/.

Then I've dockerized it, but trying to access it on the browser at http://localhost:3000/ shows ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I can see the container by running `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
       NAMES
9301a87c47af        hello-express       "/bin/sh -c 'node bi…"   4 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3000
/tcp   admiring_torvalds
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:7
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD node bin/www
EXPOSE 3000
```

I work on Windows 10 and use Docker Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

In Docker Toolbox, a container is implemented as a VM. This VM has a different IP address. I used Kinematic (a GUI for Docker Toolbox) to find the IP address of the VM and then reached it on the browser via its IP rather than localhost.